# Emit Mapper Flattering with Custom Converters

Tags: c#, mapping, emitmapper

With this configuration for some reason Conver function of Custom Converter is not called when using FlatteringConfig from EmitMapper Samples. It is called, when DefaultMapConfig is used.

The configuration:

```cs
    var userMapper = ObjectMapperManager.DefaultInstance.GetMapper<User, UserModel>(
                   new FlatteringConfig().ConvertGeneric(typeof(IList<>), typeof(IList<>),
                new DefaultCustomConverterProvider(typeof(EntityListToModelListConverter<,>))));
```

Any ideas about the potential reason?

## Solution

Look at my answer below

Comment: please put the solution as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because FlatteringConfig overrides `GetMappingOperations` function it is not calling `FilterOpertations` functions, which assigns custom converters. So adding `FilterOperations` function call to the `GetMappingOperations` solved the problem.